# Why am I getting an attribute error __enter__ for a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, attributeerror

```
def save_list():  
  f = open('data.txt', 'w')

  ii = 0

  with itemMatrix[ii] as item:

    f.write(item + '\n')

    ii += 1
```

This code keeps giving me the error:
attribute error **enter** on line 5, (with itemMatrix[ii] as item:)

why is this happening, and how do I fix it? If any more code is needed, let me know.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Because that's simply not (default) Python. Just use `item = itemMatrix[ii]`, or remove that line, and use `f.write(itemMatrix[ii] + '\n')` (which is unlikely to work, unless your matrix is an array or list and contains only strings.

Comment: Also, looks you are trying to iterate the array, but that's not what you are doing. Looks like maybe you are looking for a `for` statement or a `while`. Check for python documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def save_list():
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in itemMatrix:
            f.write(f"{item}\n")
```

(with [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) to format the elements together with a newline.)

Answer (score 0):

you probably wanted to write `for item in itemMatrix[ii]:`

the with statement uses the context management protocol.
it roughly translates to this.

```
with obj as instance:
  body(instance)

# is syntactical suger for
instance = obj.__enter__()
try:
    body(instance)
except BaseException as e:
    obj.__exit__(type(e), e, stacktrace)
else:
    obj.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

if you wanted to use the with statement then `itemMatrix[ii]` should have an **enter** method and an **exit** method. see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Comment: Based on the pseudo-loop incrementing `ii`, they probably just wanted `for item in itemMatrix:`, not `for item in itemMatrix[ii]:`